# Passing Query string values through ajax html(data)

Tags: jquery, html, sql, ajax, jsp

I use this code to pass the query string in other jsp page to pass the value to my jsp form. I am using a **sql view table** to populate the data and by using **rs.getString(1);** And actually it works. But when i create for the second input, it stops working. I debug the query, and the value was printed, but somehow, all the value was not appeared in the input control. I've tried to queried (select * from view)  and tried to get different column, and somehow,there's a column that can appear in the input box and some cannot. it's weird, since all the column was set to varchar.In this below example the column regno dont appear in the input. The jquery function below was inside my jsp form page. And the java code was from other jsp page.

```
    while (rsLoadList.next()) {
    cols="REGNO,CustNo,ENTITYTYPE ";

    queryCmd = "SELECT  " + cols + "  FROM " + rsLoadList.getString("Tbl") + 

   " WHERE "+ likeFilter  + " ORDER BY "+ rsLoadList.getString("Desc");
    PrintDebug.println("cmd2: " + queryCmd);    
    rsQuery = aDbManager.retrieveRec(queryCmd);

    String regno = "";                                      
    while (rsQuery.next()) {                                            %>
    <script>
    $('#Customer_Number').val(<%=rsQuery.getString(1)%>);
    $('#ID_Number').val(<%=rsQuery.getString(2)%>);
    </script>
    PrintDebug.println("Customer_Number: " + rsQuery.getString(1));
     PrintDebug.println("ID_Number: " + rsQuery.getString(2));
    }
    }



 function refreshRecordCustNameList(rec,filter){  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "LoadDropdownSubAccNo.jsp",
        data: "FieldFilter="+filter+"&Fieldname=" + rec + "&MappingID=<%=MappingID%>",
        success: function(data){


            $("input[id='Customer_Number']").html(''); 
        $("input[id='Customer_Number']").html(data);
                /*$("input[id='ID_Number']").html('');
             $("input[id='ID_Number']").html(data); */
        },
        error: function(msg){
            bootbox.alert({
                title:"Error"+  $("select[id='Customer_Number']").html(data),
                message: "Failed to load the list.",
            });
        }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace with document.getElementById and it works.

```
 document.getElementById('Customer_Number').value="<%=rsQuery.getString(1)%>";
 document.getElementById('ENTITYTYPE').value="<%=rsQuery.getString(8)%>";
 document.getElementById('ID_Number').value="<%=rsQuery.getString(4)%>";
```